# module has no attribute 'index'?

Tags: django

I was doing the `django` tutorials but got stuck on this one https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/.
I did the following things when I got this error `module has no attribute index`  in 
  `polls/urls.py`

```
 # This is in polls/views.py
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 def index(request):
   return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")


 #This is in polls/url.py
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
 from polls import views
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
 url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'))


#This is in mysite/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',url(r'^polls/',include('polls.urls')),url(r'^admin/',include(admin.site.urls)),)
```

PS: Up till this tutorial I have followed the tutorial 1 and 2 and have done everything accordingly.

Comment: try to restart apache, or your IDE...

Comment: if you're using the development server `manage.py runserver`, add `print views.__dict__` below `from polls import views`, what is the output?

Comment: Are you sure that you opened ` http://localhost:8000/polls/ ` ?

Comment: you named your file `poll/url.py` and you try to include `polls.urls`, check that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the file is named as polls/urls.py, in your comment you forget the 's' which looks as if you may have the file name saved wrong. This will have an effect as the last line of code relies on 'polls.urls'

The django tutorials are pretty poor when it comes to replacing previous code written and knowing when to delete previous code. Go back and check through the previous tutorials, django says 'update' or 'add' and you may end up deleting code instead of just adding to it like I unfortunately did.

I am no expert, but i have just been through the tutorials and suffered a huge amount of obstacles, of which i managed to overcome. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Index variable ise not defined under views. In polls/url.py use this code: 
"path('', views.home, name='home')"

Try using **home** instead of **index**